# Transferring existing MySql database records to SqLite

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I've been searching the net for quite a while but haven't found a appropriate method to accomplish my task.
My goal is to set a local database for windows phone 8. The problem is that I have a lot of data and moreover, lot of tables(15) which are logically "all" connected. I've seen numerous methods on how to build a local database but I think that it would take ages to write all of this classes(events, properties, reflection,asyncs...) and connect all of my tables writing c# code manually.
What I would like is to transfer my Mysql database records to SqLite and somehow store this database locally on wp8.
Is such thing possible in a short time or must I built the entire database and insert all data one by one using c#.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do this is with a ETL tool ( Extract, transform, load tools ).

I highly recommend [Pentaho Data integration and Business Analytics](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/), it has an open source version, the one I am putting on this link, and a paid one.

It is very intuitive to use. Just select the source ( in your case a mysql database ), use the transformation tools you need ( data integrity check, relationship check, etc ) and finally select your destination ( a sqlite file).

Comment: tnx for the recomendation but I m searching for another way to solve my problem

Comment: @esunic do you want to do it in real time?
Other idea, create a web service that translates the mysql database to the sqlite database. The problem is that you are going to have to do a lot of validation.

Comment: I still have some trouble, I installed cygwin and packages which should allow me to fully use the script found on github. I posted another question related to cygwin.